# Nesting <article> and <h1> tags?

Tags: css, html, tags, nested

## Question:

Which of these is the proper way to nest the `<h1>` and `<article>` tags, and what is your reasoning behind it?

### Choice A:

```
<article>
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
    <p>Here's some text and whatnot.</p>
    <p>Here's another paragraph filled with other text and other whatnots.</p>
</article>
```

### Choice B:

```
<div class="post">
    <h1>Here's a Really Awesome Title</h1>
    <article>
        <p>Here's a paragraph with text and whatnot.</p>
        <p>And here's another paragraph. I think this one is pretty awesome too.</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Opinions seem mixed about this, and I'm not 100% which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ⚠ **Warning** ⚠
>
> This answer is severely out-of-date and relies on the now-obsolete document outline algorithm.

## both are fine

@David Dorward has a great answer, and I was going to comment to expand on it, but when I realized my comment was getting too long I decided I'd just add my own answer instead.

The `h#` elements semantically belong to their parents.

This `h1` is the primary header for the **page**

```
<body>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</body>
```

While this `h1` is the primary header for the **article**

```
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </article>
</body>
```

This allows us to expand the usage of `h#` elements in meaningful ways as follows:

```
<body>
  <h1>Blag Tottle</h1>
  <article>
    <h1>Article 1 Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Article 2 Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc</p>
  </article>
</body>
```

Now you may want to separate your article heading some more, which is a perfect application of the `header` element:

```
<body>
  <h1>Blag Tottle</h1>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Article 1 Title</h1>
      <span class="author">And not a mouse</span>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Article 2 Title</h1>
      <span class="author">Somebody</span>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc</p>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer! Don't forget that instead of putting `<header><h1>Blah</h1><span>Bloopity</span></header>`, you could also use `<hgroup><h1>Blah</h1><h3>Author</h3></hgroup>` to delimit your headings.

Comment: @Nick Anderegg, I would say that's a semantic misuse of `h3` to be used as an author, although if it *were* a sub-title the `hgroup` would be applicable. To be honest, it really makes very little difference overall.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I meant `<h2></h2>`. But I was trying to point out that if you are using multiple things under in a header for an article, one good option is `<hgroup></hgroup>`. I would use a `<span></span>` for the author, however.

Comment: <hgroup> has been removed from the HTML5 specification

Comment: A practical consideration to keep in mind is that per the [HTML5 Rendering specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#sections-and-headings), an `h1` element inside an `article` is by default smaller than one outside of one: its `font-size` is then only `1.50em` instead of `2em`, the same as the default `font-size` of an `h2` element. (An `h2` inside an `article` is similarly shrunk, but only if a sibling of the `h1`, which the `header` prevents. That is, in `<article><header><h1>…</header><h2>…</article>`, the `h1` and `h2` are the same size.)

Comment: @lucas.werkmeister, websites so very rarely keep default sizing for headers that I'm less concerned about that particular oversight than I am about the fact that my answer is severely out of date and relies on the document outline algorithm which [never really took off](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html).

Comment: the use of multiple h1 on a single page is not semantically correct

Comment: @KoutaNakano, yes, that's what I was referring to in my previous comment from 4 years ago. I've gone ahead and added a warning to this answer as I don't have the time to rewrite it, and I can't delete it as it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

Headings are scoped to article elements (and other [sectioning elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#sectioning-content)). The heading should be inside the article to which it applies.

> The first element of heading content in an element of sectioning content represents the heading for that section

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections

Choice A is better if it is the heading for *that* article.

Choice B is better if it is the heading for all the articles that follow it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using first option. Because , article's mean is *[a part of external content](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_article.asp)* . So this content should have a header.

Answer (score 0):

Choice A. The chapter headings (which H1 is too) are part of you article.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the heading is part of the article.

This is really down to personal taste as far as I can tell. You won't get a right or wrong answer as long as you're writing valid HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different articles, you can use multiple h1 per page. for cases where several articles are on one page.
In this way, you can also use it for show in Schema.

```
 <section>

  <article>
   <h1>Taste</h1>
   <p>They taste lovely.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
   <h1>Sweet</h1>
   <p>Red apples are sweeter than green ones.</p>
  </article>

 </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Headers that talk about the article *(meta-headers)* should be out of `<article>`, headers that are part of the article (chapters, for example) should be in `<article>`.

All of that just IMHO.